# How to use Like operator to match a string in one table to a sub-string into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to two tables `Table 1` & `Table 2`. `Table 1` has customer details and `Table 2` has transaction details:

```
    Table 1                      Table 2        

Col1    CustCode        Col1    TrainsactionID      Col3
11      AAA             101     2139812/BBB/98waw   EDF
22      BBB             102     2398472/CCC/18sdf   QWD
33      CCC             103     9283743/AAA/76afa   VFB
44      DDD             104     2983472/BBB/123as   FGV
```

I need to select the customer codes (strings) `AAA`, `BBB` and `CCC` from column `"CustCode"` of `table 1` as they exist as a substring in column `"TransactionID"` of `table 2`.
Is there a way I can write a correlated subquery using `'Like %'` operator to fetch all such matching `CustCodes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
    select A.col1, a.custcode,b.transactionid,b.col3
    from table1 a inner join table2 b
       on a.CustCode like concat('%',b.TrainsactionID,'%')
```

Answer (score 5):

You may use a join, on the condition that the customer code from the first table appears in the path of the transaction ID from the second table.

```
SELECT t1.Col1, t1.CustCode, t2.Col1, t2.TrainsactionID, t2.Col3
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.TrainsactionID LIKE '%/' + t1.CustCode + '/%';
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that this join condition is not optimal and probably can't use an index.  If you have a long term need for these tables, then consider setting up join columns which can use equality operators.